# pop up confirmation delete for php

Tags: javascript, php, html, database, xampp

So my code is below which read from dmgeqdelete.php that will instantly delete data from database. `<td align="center">
<a href="dmgeqdelete.php?damagedID=<?php echo $row["damagedID"]; ?>" >Delete</a>
</td>`

Im trying to add a pop up confirmation for above code. i have tried `<td align="center">
<a href="dmgeqdelete.php?damagedID=<?php echo $row["damagedID"]; ?>" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')">Delete</a>
</td>` end up with no action happen

dmgeqdelete.php

```html
<?php
include('dbConfig.php');
$damagedID=$_REQUEST['damagedID'];
$query = "DELETE FROM damagedeq WHERE damagedID=$damagedID"; 
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query) or die ( mysqli_error());
header("Location: dmgeqview.php"); 
?>
```

full code

```html
<?php
include('dbConfig.php');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>View Damaged Equipment Records</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="form">
    <p><a href="report.php">Home</a> | <a href="index.php">Logout</a></p>
    <h2>View Records</h2>
    <table width="100%" border="1" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th><strong>No</strong></th>
          <th><strong>Damage ID's</strong></th>
          <th><strong>EQ ID's</strong></th>
          <th><strong>Student ID's</strong></th>
          <th><strong>Staff ID's</strong></th>
          <th><strong>Date reported</strong></th>
          <th><strong>Date repaired</strong></th>
          <th><strong>Equipment Status</strong></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <?php
$count=1;
$sel_query="Select * from damagedeq ORDER BY damagedID desc;";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sel_query);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { ?>
          <tr>
            <td align="center">
              <?php echo $count; ?>
            </td>
            <td align="center">
              <?php echo $row["damagedID"]; ?>
            </td>
            <td align="center">
              <?php echo $row["equipmentID"]; ?>
            </td>
            <td align="center">
              <?php echo $row["studentID"]; ?>
            </td>
            <td align="center">
              <?php echo $row["staffID"]; ?>
            </td>
            <td align="center">
              <?php echo $row["dateReported"]; ?>
            </td>
            <td align="center">
              <?php echo $row["dateRepaired"]; ?>
            </td>
            <td align="center">
              <?php echo $row["equipmentStatus"]; ?>
            </td>
            <td align="center">
              <a href="dmgequp.php?damagedID=<?php echo $row[" damagedID "]; ?>">Edit</a>
            </td>
            <td align="center">
              <a href="dmgeqdelete.php?damagedID=<?php echo $row[" damagedID "]; ?>">Delete</a>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <?php $count++; } ?>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Use actual click listener function where you handle the confirm, then ajax to POST the data to php, and PDO with prepared statements in php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you just need to stop the further execution of the code

```
onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')"
```

adding the `return false` at the end like this

```
onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?'); return false;"
```

When clicking on **cancel** nothing will happen, but if click on **ok** it will go to link
Here is a full code snippet

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>View Damaged Equipment Records</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="form">
    <p><a href="report.php">Home</a> | <a href="index.php">Logout</a></p>
    <h2>View Records</h2>
    <table width="100%" border="1" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th><strong>No</strong></th>
          <th><strong>Damage ID's</strong></th>
          <th><strong>EQ ID's</strong></th>
          <th><strong>Student ID's</strong></th>
          <th><strong>Staff ID's</strong></th>
          <th><strong>Date reported</strong></th>
          <th><strong>Date repaired</strong></th>
          <th><strong>Equipment Status</strong></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td align="center">000</td>
          <td align="center">111</td>
          <td align="center">222</td>
          <td align="center">333</td>
          <td align="center">444</td>
          <td align="center">555</td>
          <td align="center">666</td>
          <td align="center">777</td>
          <td align="center">
            <a href="dmgequp.php?damagedID=aaa">Edit</a>
          </td>
          <td align="center">
            <a href="dmgeqdelete.php?damagedID=bbb" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?'); return false;">Delete</a>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, so basicly i need to stop the further execution of the code href="dmgeqdelete.php?damagedID=<?php echo $row["damagedID"]; ?>"

Comment: No, you don't need to return extra false. Clicking Cancel/No already returns false. You probably had some typo there on your first try. Just remember this is really bad practice, never manipulate anything with GET variables. This will get your database emptied. See here: [https://jsfiddle.net/ou0szc3r/](https://jsfiddle.net/ou0szc3r/)

Comment: Hard to do tell since OP didn't include his original code where used it, only referenced to it. Only thing to learn is that `confirm` returns `true` or `false`, and nothing after it is triggered, as you can see from the jsfiddle. You can even remove `return false;` from your snippet and notice that it makes no difference.